# ReactJS ..event handler works with one of the props but not all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send id prop to a even handler to handle an event .I have a map function sending the name and id as props as below.    When I Try to send the id to event handler in Delete Todo component I get id as undefined in console.log().But when I use the Name prop,console.log() works fine. Any idea what I am actually missing. Please help.

```
    const todolistt=todolist.map(td=>{
            return (
                <div>
              
                    <Deletetodo todo={td.id} name={td.name}  />
    
               </div>
            )
        })
     const handleDelete=(id)=>{
        console.log(id)//Getting undefined
    }
    const Deletetodo = ({id,name}) => {
        return (
    
            <div>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <p onClick={()=>{handleDelete(id)}}>X</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    const handleDelete=(name)=>{
        console.log(name)//Name appers
    }
    const Deletetodo = ({id,name}) => {
    
        return (
    
            <div>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <p onClick={()=>{handleDelete(name)}}>X</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to name the prop "id" like this:

```
<Deletetodo id={td.id} name={td.name}  />
```

You're passing in a prop called "todo" but looking for a prop called "id"